# How do you use the sideEffect() method in the Gremlin npm package

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I've tried various ways of calling sideEffect(), but none have worked, I can't find any documentation or examples online, and the source code is a bit too abstract for me to understand without spending considerably longer looking at it.

As an example:

```
const y = await g.V().hasId('a4b64522-9cda-1b34-8f76-634242933a0d').sideEffect('drop()').next();
```

Results in

```
Error: Server error: {"requestId":"8915089a-cde3-4861-b73a-2534cefbc0b2","code":"InternalFailureException","detailedMessage":"Could not locate method: NeptuneGraphTraversal.sideEffect([drop()])"} (599)
```

I'm running these traversals against AWS Neptune in case that matters (although running similar queries through Python and the Gremlin Console against Neptune work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sideEffect()` step takes an [anonymous traversal](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/gremlins-anatomy/#_anonymous_traversals) so the syntax I provided in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465757/1831717) should work equally well in every Gremlin Language Variant including javascript:

```
g.V().hasId('a4b64522-9cda-1b34-8f76-634242933a0d').sideEffect(drop())
```

`drop()` is of course spawned from `__` and should be part of your [standard imports](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_common_imports_2) and can be called more explicitly as:

```
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
g.V().hasId('a4b64522-9cda-1b34-8f76-634242933a0d').sideEffect(__.drop())
```

The error you describe in your question is simply related to your usage where you pass `drop()` as a string value. That said, I suppose it's possible that neptune doesn't support `sideEffect()` as a step at all?? You could test it with a more simple traversal with legitimate syntax and see if you get the same error:

```
g.V().hasId('a4b64522-9cda-1b34-8f76-634242933a0d').sideEffect(__.constant(1))
```

If that traversal returns a `Vertex` with the specified id you were querying for and you don't see an error then I would think `sideEffect()` as being a supported step. Perhaps someone with more Neptune experience will be able to offer a more official answer for you.

Comment: I can tell from experience that Neptune support the sideEffect() step.

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried to create an anonymous traversal, but obviously not the right way!